# phpmyadmin can't login on initial install (mac osx)

Tags: mysql, macos, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to get up and running on MySQL and phpMyAdmin but keep having problems with logging into phpMyAdmin.  I get "#2002 Cannot log in to the MySQL server" when using both the default username "root" with no password and with a password I've set up via the terminal.

Here's the relevant portion of my config.inc.php file:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'admin'; //I have also tried 'root' here with no password
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'PASSWORD';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
```

What I've tried:

restarting Apache and MySQL

re-installing both

editing config.inc.php a few different ways...in the root phpMyAdmin folder after creating it in a /config folder.

I'm utterly stuck.

system/version details: 
Mac OSX 10.7.5
phpMyAdmin 3.5.7
MySQL 5.5.28

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try installing mampp or xampp.. Everything should work out of the box there..

Comment: That did it...quick and easy, just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 5):

If you use `localhost`, it'll try to access mysql through the socket.  You can try one of two things:

1. change `localhost` to `127.0.0.1`
2. Set the socket from `/var/mysql/mysql.sock` to `/tmp/mysql.sock` in your php.ini

You should also do some sanity checks, like making sure the database is up and running by connecting to it using the username/password you're using for phpMyAdmin.

Comment: I tried that earlier on...didn't quite do it.  XAMPP did it though.

Comment: WORKED!  THANKS!!  There were like 4 places in the php.ini file where I had to change it from /var/mysql/mysql.sock to /tmp/mysql.sock.  Some tutorials propose creating a sym-link from /var/mysql/mysql.sock to /tmp/sock instead of changing ini.  I personally think changing the ini file is easier to maintain, that's why they have ini files.

Comment: Changing 'localhost' to '127.0.0.1' worked for me on Yosemite, smh.

Answer (score 0):

for me i just **restart** and followed the following steps

1. in General Tab click on start
2. in services Tab click on Start All
3. in Network Tab enable all ports
   and try again on the browser